# Raspberry Pi +Hydro + Openni/freenect

Tags: kinect, ros-hydro, raspberrypi, freenect, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am very new to ROS, raspberry pi and linux. I already install Hydro into my raspberry pi. I can run roscore.

Next I want to run freenect_launch. I can'y sudo apt-get install freenect_stack. It say Unable to locate package freenect_stack. I check with apt-cache search freenect. It didn't have anything about freenect_stack/freenect_launch

When I apt-cache search openni there is nothing. Should I add source.list? how do i do that?

How to i apt-get freenect_stack and use roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch ?

Sorry I am very new to all this. Do please link me if already have answered.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193741/raspberry-pi-+hydro-+-openni/freenect/) by [qlouis76](https://answers.ros.org/users/20341/qlouis76/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-09-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on 2014-09-29**:
Are you trying to connect a Microsoft Kinect to a raspberry pi? What linux are you using in rpi?

**Comment by [qlouis76](https://answers.ros.org/users/20341/qlouis76/) on 2014-09-29**:
Debian. Thanks for your reply. I follow this tutorial to install hydro. http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20Hydro%20on%20RaspberryPi

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on 2014-09-29**:
If you are trying to connect Microsoft kinect to raspberry pi, it is not possible due to limitations in bandwidth on the rpi.

**Comment by [qlouis76](https://answers.ros.org/users/20341/qlouis76/) on 2014-09-29**:
Are you sure? I search the net, there are some successful project on kinect and raspberry pi

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-03-28**:
I've got indigo running on a rpi2B (raspbian:jessie) and the kinect works with the freenect drivers. I've read that you can compile openni from github and that works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried interfacing kinect with a beaglebone black, I could not get the data stream from kinect. Try Odroid it is much faster. If you still want to use kinect with raspberry pi, you must either overclock it or  [like this](https://code.google.com/p/haptic-belt-for-the-blind/), doing it from scratch. ROS +rpi + kinect cannot be done as it requires more processing power. Most of the projects that people have done would include a desktop pc to which they interface the kinect and stream the control data to rpi to control some actuators.

---

Originally posted by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) with karma: 137 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qlouis76](https://answers.ros.org/users/20341/qlouis76/) on 2014-09-30**:
thank you for your explanation. I think i need to shift my work to using a laptop to process data from kinect and use raspberry pi as a controller.

Do you mind to share me some link about the project that kinect with PC + raspberry

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-03-28**:
I was able to do it with freenect + indigo + rpi2B

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I battled with the Kinect on my Pi for a while and gave up. I suggest using the ASUS Xtion . I managed to get that working without too much difficulty. Remember to use OpenNI2 though.

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qlouis76](https://answers.ros.org/users/20341/qlouis76/) on 2014-09-30**:
I wish i already had a kinect ready. So just thought of using it for a project.